# Is there a way to get all the backend request made by a dynamic website via python

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

looking into a website's code and the browser console in order to find relevant links where the data came from is a bit of a hassle when it comes to web-scraping.

Is there a way for me to get all the request made by a dynamic website using python.

A way to get all the dynamically requested links by a website.